# Why does python crash when using csv.writer with QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

Tags: python, python-3.7

When I create create a csv file in python 3.7 using `csv.writer` and `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` python crashes with the message

```
python: Objects/typeobject.c:3117: _PyType_Lookup: Assertion `!PyErr_Occurred()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This happens in python 3.7.4 and 3.7.3 but not 3.6.9.
It does not happen if I don't pass `csv.QUOTE_NONUMERIC`.

All versions of python were compiled at the same time on Linux Mint 19.

As I could not find any references to this issue online I assume it is not a bug in python or csv. It seems likely that I was missing a dependency when I compiled python, however I have never been able to file a complete list of dependencies so I'm not sure what I could be missing.

Steps to reproduce:

```
import csv
with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f:
 csv.writer(f, csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: Any core dump of the Python interpreter is a Python bug. If you do something wrong it should produce a reasonable error message, not crash.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m test`? I just tried this on `3.7.4` on Ubuntu 18.04 and there was no problem. Same with `3.7.0` on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MattM , I ran `python -m test` and the `csv` test passed, however `test_concurrent_features` and `test_pdb` failed. I wonder if they rely on a common dependency that was missing at compile time. Otherwise I don't think these failures can be related.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting should be passed to csv.writer by as a keyword, not positional, argument.

```
import csv
with open('tmp.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Otherwise it is passed to the `dialect` parameter, which expects a string which is used to select a subclass of `csv.Dialect` to use to format the output. As `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` is an `int` I believe that it is being passed to a function in the c module _csv and causing a low level error.